# SpicIE Internet Explorer Plugin: How to access rendered HTML?

Tags: internet-explorer, mshtml

I am attempting to write an Internet Explorer (IE8) plugin using SpicIE (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE).  Inside the OnDocumentComplete method, I am able to access the HTML of the page by doing the following:

```
private static void SamplePlugin_OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object url){
    SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 browser = HostInstance.BrowserRef as SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2;
    mshtml.HTMLDocument htmlDocument = browser.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
    String html = htmlDocument.documentElement.outerHTML;
}
```

My problem is, some (most) pages have additional calls back to the server after the initial page is loaded.  How can I access the "rendered" HTML of the final page displayed to the user?  For example, one site I'm looking at loads, then has AJAX calls that fill DIVs with text.  But when I use the code above, I am not getting this text.  I am getting the page before the dynamic content is loaded.  Any ideas??

I really appreciate it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

With IE8 this is a nearly impossible task since it doesn't support [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html).

You need mutation events to detect changes made to the DOM (and this is exactly what happens when AJAXed info is added to the page). So your only chance is to do some kind of polling to detect changed elements, but this will have a noticable performance impact. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  How do you suggest listening/polling for changed elements using Spicie?  On a side note, I've noticed that the built in IE8 developer tools is able to display the rendered HTML, maybe there is a way to tap into that?

Comment: I don't think you can tap into the developer tools. And often you just cannot get the "final" page displayed to the user because you will never know whether it is really final or not. There might be things going on constantly changing the HTML. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm writing a debugger and am looking to make something similar to FireBug's HTML tree structure functionality.